# Git --> Committed, revert -m 1 commitID, remerged, and merged code does not build in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, git-revert

Note:  Utilizing sourcetree for Git interaction

I committed 17 ticket branches to the QA branch.  QA then came back and said the Jenkins build was blocked.  I assumed it was due to conflicts in two of the branches, that I had resolved with my branch (theirs), rather than the QA branch (mine).

Based on a coworker's advice, I used the terminal git command, revert -m 1, to revert the commits for those two branches.

We then found out that the error was being caused by an orphaned sass file in a completely different branch, that did not have a conflict with the QA branch.  I removed the orphaned sass file from the offending branch, and remerged that branch into the QA branch.  We then confirmed that the Jenkins package built.

Next, I created two new branches from the master branch for the two tickets that were reverted, and merged the code into the new branches.  Then I merged the new branches into the QA branch, once again resolved the conflicts with my ticket branches, and the Jenkins package built.

Come to find out, the updated code for the defects is not displaying on the site when the Jenkins package is applied to the QA server.  When I open the ticket sass and css files through the QA branch, the code is correct and matches the code from my branch.

Any ideas on why the Jenkins build does not match the QA branch, or how I can redo the merge so that it does show up?

Comment: Does jenkins displays an error or simply outdate code? Did you checked jenkins workspace ($JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<JOBNAME>/workspace) for your project? What code does it displays there?

Comment: There is not a build error.  I had not checked the jenkins workspace.  The workspace is still showing the old code for the project in the sass file, but the correct code in the css file.  Looks like the sass is outdated!

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in that direction.  That points out the problem.  Now, hopefully, I just need to resolve the outdated file.